# converting to Barycentric coordinate system

Tags: math, actionscript, 3d, coordinate-systems

I have a set of planes which I have calculated the points of intersection in the standard XYZ cartesian coordinate system. I have used actionscript.

I would like to project the intersection points (shown circled in blue in the pictures below) down to the triangular base and then calculate the Barycentric coordinates.

[image: plane intersection]
[image: plane intersection 2]

Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: which one is the triangular base you want to use?

Comment: The base, the one at the bottom

Answer (score 1):

[This is a good link](http://crackthecode.us/barycentric/barycentric_coordinates.html) showing and explaining how to convert from Cartesian to Barycentric coordinates

Comment: +1 for quite possibly the most straight forward explanation of Barycentric coords out there.

Comment: Future here: The link no longer works, but you can use a waybackmachine and resurrect it: http://web.archive.org/web/20090609111431/http://www.crackthecode.us/barycentric/barycentric_coordinates.html The photos are down though. So if anyone has a better link, please post it.

Comment: Link is broken… Usually it's good to sum up the content of a linked page.